# jQuery UI Datepicker widget stopped working after upgrading from 1.9m1 to 1.9.2

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have multiple datepickers on the same page linked to the text inputs without IDs and marked with class "calendar"

Initialization code is pretty trivial:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.calendar").datepicker({
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: 'd-M-yy'
    });
});
```

Everything worked like a charm but after upgrading to from jQuery 1.7 + jQueryUI 1.9m1 to jQuery 1.8.3 + jQueryUI 1.9.2 functionality is broken: there are no more datepicker widgets popping up when inputs get focus. I can see via Chrome dev tools that the widget is initialized and all input fields are properly wired but it simply remains hidden on click.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: Issue has been resolved - it was a code conflict beyond jQuery packages

Comment: Works for me.  Note that jsFiddle is terribly slow right now.  http://jsfiddle.net/jKG5S/.  p.s. if you go to the left hand side you can see the resources I use.  If you mouse over the asset names, you'll see I'm using jQuery UI 1.9.2.

Comment: Ok, I found conflicting code in another library loaded in parallel

Comment: What did it conflict with?  I have what might be the same issue..

Comment: Frankly speaking I don't remember at the moment, app had a bunch of libraries and flat update created a conflict somewhere